# What are my guests doing under water?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

To the left of the screenshot, you can see some guests staying underwater. They have never moved since I noticed them, but the command <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd> indicate that they are still alive.

I thought they were not able to climb up, so I channeled some ramps around the bank to help them, but they still remained there, without moving even a bit.

What's wrong with them?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any locations for them to visit? Maybe without a tavern/temple/library they won't path anywhere.

Comment: @Paul Yes, I have a tavern and a library, so all kinds of guests, i.e. mercenaries, scholars and performers, should have some place to go.

Comment: Is it possible this pond or the level above it is a meeting zone or location? Or even a water/fishing zone that got bugged or misassigned?

Comment: I've observed this too! I created a tavern that was ringed with a channel filled with water, and I would regularly find 90-100% of the channel tiles occupied by visitors. No problem pathing out, no health problems, no explanation. They just seem to love swimming.

Answer (score 4):

Late reply, but this does appear to be a known bug:
http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=9254

The person confirming the bug report was able to get the visitor to path out of the water by clearing the visitor tag from the visitor using dfhack. I assume if you did that, you'd want to then reapply the visitor tag once they've pathed to the tavern.